# Rabbitmq-c library doesn't dynamically linked in Debian 8

Tags: c, gcc, debian-jessie, rabbitmq-c

### The goal: make Rabbitmq-c dynamically linked via gcc (https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c).

**Project is called *storeman*:**

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <amqp_tcp_socket.h>
#include <amqp.h>
#include <amqp_framing.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *const *argv)
{
    amqp_connection_state_t conn;
    conn=amqp_new_connection();
    exit(0); //Everything else is deleted for testing
}
```

**1. Download, compile and install library.**

In new `build` folder inside rabbitmq-c download path:

> cmake ..
>
> cmake --build .
>
> cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
>
> make
>
> make install

Finally it does the following succesfull output:

```
[ 15%] Built target rabbitmq
...
[100%] Built target test_tables
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/librabbitmq.pc
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4.2.1
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so.4
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.so
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librabbitmq.a
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/amqp.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/amqp_framing.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/amqp_tcp_socket.h
-- Up-to-date: /usr/local/include/amqp_ssl_socket.h
```

The library files are installed into

- /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ (librabbitmq.so and librabbitmq.so.4 points as links to librabbitmq.so.4.2.1, and there is librabbitmq.a)
- /usr/local/include/, where all needed header files are resides (amqp.h
  amqp_framing.h amqp_ssl_socket.h amqp_tcp_socket.h)

**2. Use gcc.**

> gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o
>   storeman storeman.c -lrabbitmq

GCC exits with:

```
error while loading shared libraries: librabbitmq.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

In the same time it may succesfully be compiled as static, using librabbitmq.a, that confuses me a lot... Will be very gratefull for any help.

Comment: Probably you need to change `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable. What is your output of  `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

Comment: It's amazing.
Static is compiled by "gcc -static -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -o storeman storeman.c -lrabbitmq" with no problem but dynamic can't link without LD_LIBRARY_PATH set...
Answer is yours: "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" instead of "/usr/local/lib" that is very strange for me.. But I'am new in writing in C for linux. So many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the issue may be that file /etc/ld.so.conf.d/rabbitmq.conf is missing the .../lib/... subdirectory in its content.  When I update that file's content to this it works for me (finds the rabbitmq shared lib):

```
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Note, run `sudo ldconfig` after saving the change.

This appears to be a rabbitmq git installation bug - I cloned and built from branch master on Feb 22, 2018 on Ubu-17.

Comment: Wasn't very clear about that - sorry -- the git clone was this:  git clone https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git ... that's rabbitmq-c, not rabbitmq !